# trying to figure out how an HTTP POST is being made to twilio

Tags: twilio

When I go to Monitor -> Logs -> Calls I see that my application is making an HTTP POST to [https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Account](https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%7BAccount) SID}/Calls/{Call SID}.json with the following contents:

StatusCallbackMethod=POST&Method=POST&Url=https://domain.tld/path/to/whatever&FallbackMethod=POST

After that Twilio then makes an HTTP POST to https://domain.tld/path/to/whatever

The problem is....  idk where the HTTP POST is coming from [https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Account](https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%7BAccount) SID}/Calls/{Call SID}.json . What Javascript / PHP functions in the Twilio SDK would result in such a request being sent?

Comment: Can you explain your use-case and why you are interested in this information? The point of the SDK is abstracting all HTTP calls away from the developer.

Comment: @IObert - after the app that I inherited sends this HTTP request Twilio makes an HTTP POST to https://domain.tld/path/to/whatever. https://domain.tld/path/to/whatever then responds with a TwiML that directs Twilio to play a message and then hangup. I've been asked to change this behavior. Since, near as I can tell, the only place this URL is mentioned is in this HTTP Request to Twilio I'm trying to track it down.

Comment: This URL isn't in TaskRouter -> Default Workspace -> Settings, TaskRouter -> Default Workspace -> Workflows -> Default Fifo Workflow or Programmable Voice -> TwiML -> TwiML Apps. If there are any other places in the Twilio Console where a URL can be set I'm unaware of them.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has numerous internal webhooks that are automatically dispatched on various events relating to calls, SMS, and others. These are internal to Twilio systems and hence you won't find that they are sent from your own application code.

You can view those for voice calls [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/voice-webhooks) but they include an incoming call, completition of calls, and recording related.